# How to change icon in <mat-select> in angular material?

Tags: css, angular, angular-material

I have a problem with the arrows in mat-nav-list, I have to achieve the following:

- If list is dropped down arrow is directed to down,
- In other cases directed to right.

```
 <mat-form-field>
    <mat-select placeholder="Select">
      <mat-option value="option">Option</mat-option>
    </mat-select>
  </mat-form-field>
```

I've tried to hide the mat-select-arrow in css, but this doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `transform: rotate(-90deg);` to rotate the arrow to right and on focus to rotate to down.

Also use [`:host` and `::ng-deep`](https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-host-context/)

[Working example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mat-select-data-ewjv3y)

```
:host mat-select ::ng-deep .mat-select-arrow{
transform: rotate(-90deg);
}

::ng-deep .mat-form-field.mat-focused.mat-primary .mat-select-arrow{
  transform: rotate(0deg);
}
```

Comment: How it works with <mat-nav-list> and <mat-list-item>?